# can I use same consent of graph API in web and powershell script?

Tags: laravel, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I used username/password flow in my laravel app before, and it was working well. but now I have to use a single sign-on and ask for consent during login. It is working fine on the web but I also run some Powershell script in the background and where the problem arises. I was able to connect different cmdlets because I had a username/password before with

```
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $cred
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $cred -AzureEnvironment AzureCloud
```

but now I don't have a username/password, So how to run my Powershell script? I am using https://github.com/dcblogdev/laravel-microsoft-graph package in my app to ask for consent and single sign-on. It is working well and I can make the call to Microsoft Graph API successfully. But I don't know how to manage the backend part that was developed in powershell script. Consent flow give me a bearer token and I tried to use this token in powershell script like

> Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName 'divyesh@myorg.com' -AccessToken 'eyJ0eXAi...'

but then I got to know that Powershell cmdlets use JWT tokens and not bearers. I tried googling but not found any solution.

Comment: Read documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/connect-azuread?view=azureadps-2.0

Comment: So your question is basically "How do I authenticate users of a PS script using my Laravel database?" That's way too broad to be a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with Laravel on Azure, you will likely be interacting with Azure resources such as App Services, databases, and storage accounts. In this case, you should use the [`Connect-AzAccount` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/connect-azaccount?view=azps-10.0.0) from the [Az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/?view=azps-10.0.0), as it is designed to manage and interact with Azure resources.

The `Connect-AzureAD` cmdlet from the AzureAD module is specifically for managing Azure Active Directory resources, such as users, groups, and applications. If you need to manage Azure AD resources in the context of your Laravel application, you can use the `Connect-AzureAD` cmdlet.

Reading "[Microsoft Graph using MSAL with PowerShell](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2019/10/31/microsoft-graph-using-msal-with-powershell/)", you could use the [`Get-MsalToken` script](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MSAL.PS/4.2.1.1/Content/Get-MsalToken.ps1) to get an access token (not a bearer token)
used by `Connect-AzAccount`.

Make sure the `Az` PowerShell module is installed (`Install-Module -Name Az`)

Use the `Get-MsalToken` cmdlet to obtain an access token:

```
$clientId = "<Your-Client-ID>"
$clientSecret = "<Your-Client-Secret>"
$tenantId = "<Your-Tenant-ID>"
$resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
$scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"

$accessToken = (Get-MsalToken -ClientId $clientId -ClientSecret $clientSecret -TenantId $tenantId -Resource $resource -Scope $scope).AccessToken
```

Use the access token to connect to Exchange Online and Azure:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -AccessToken $accessToken
Connect-AzAccount -AccessToken $accessToken -AccountId 'divyesh@myorg.com'
```

Do not forget that you will need to grant the necessary API permissions to your application in the Azure portal for this to work.
And keep in mind that the access token will expire after a certain period (usually 1 hour), so you may need to refresh it if your script runs for a longer duration.

---

> I can get the token successfully using the above method but `Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName divyesh@myorg.com -AccessToken $accessToken` gives me the error:
>
> `UnAuthorized At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ExchangeOnlineManagement\3.1.0\netFramework\ExchangeOnlineManagement.psm1:733 char:21`

The [`Connect-ExchangeOnline` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/connect-exchangeonline?view=exchange-ps) from the [ExchangeOnlineManagement module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps) (`Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement`) requires a valid Exchange Online PowerShell session, which is authenticated using a different mechanism than the Microsoft Graph API.

To authenticate with Exchange Online using an access token, you can use the `New-PSSession` cmdlet to create a remote PowerShell session and then import the ExchangeOnlineManagement module into that session.
For example:

```
$accessToken = "<Your-Access-Token>"
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $null -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)
Import-PSSession $session -DisableNameChecking
Connect-ExchangeOnline -AccessToken $accessToken
```

This code creates a remote PowerShell session to Exchange Online using the `New-PSSession` cmdlet, imports the ExchangeOnlineManagement module into that session using the `Import-PSSession` cmdlet, and then connects to Exchange Online using the `Connect-ExchangeOnline` cmdlet with the access token.

Do make sure that the account associated with the access token has the necessary permissions to access Exchange Online.

---

> It is also asking a username/password.
> Is there is any way to connect my web-app-user that grants consent on the web-app, and can I log in that web-app-user in Microsoft Graph API and in PowerShell at the same time?

Yes, you can use the same user that grants consent on the web app to authenticate with Microsoft Graph API and PowerShell simultaneously. To achieve this, you'll need to use the OAuth 2.0 authorization code grant flow to obtain an access token and a refresh token for the user. You can then use the access token to authenticate with Microsoft Graph API in your Laravel app and use the refresh token to obtain a new access token for PowerShell.

First, Implement the OAuth 2.0 authorization code grant flow in your Laravel app to obtain an access token and a refresh token for the user. You can follow the Microsoft documentation on [Authorization Code Grant Flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) for guidance.
Store the refresh token securely in your application.

Then, when you need to run the PowerShell script, use the stored refresh token to obtain a new access token for the user, using the `Get-MsalToken` cmdlet mentioned above, with the `-RefreshToken` parameter:

```
$clientId = "<Your-Client-ID>"
$clientSecret = "<Your-Client-Secret>"
$tenantId = "<Your-Tenant-ID>"
$refreshToken = "<Your-Stored-Refresh-Token>"

$accessToken = (Get-MsalToken -ClientId $clientId -ClientSecret $clientSecret -TenantId $tenantId -RefreshToken $refreshToken).AccessToken
```

Use the access token to authenticate with Exchange Online and Azure AD in PowerShell:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -AccessToken $accessToken
Connect-AzAccount -AccessToken $accessToken -AccountId 'divyesh@myorg.com'
```

Comment: I can get the token successfully using the above method but Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName divyesh@myorg.com -AccessToken $accessToken gives me "UnAuthorized
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ExchangeOnlineManagement\3.1.0\netFramework\ExchangeOnlineManagement.psm1:733 char:21" error

Comment: It is also asking a username/password. Does there is any way to connect my web-app-user that grants consent on the web-app and I can login that web-app-user in Microsoft Graph API and in Powershell at same time?

Comment: I have tried that but could not able to connect exchange-online and azuread. it is giving me UnAuthorized response. I have asked separate question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76454873/could-not-login-using-access-token-from-powershell