# Could not login using access token from powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the refresh token to get an access token and then trying to connect to **ExchangeOnline** and **AzureAD** like

```
$clientId = "7b2cd291-87e9-49fc-888e-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
$clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$tenantId = "baf62cb4-4cc6-4af9-a3c1-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
$refreshToken = "xxxxxxxx..."
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

$body = "client_id=" + $clientId + "&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&refresh_token=" + $refreshToken + "&grant_type=refresh_token&client_secret=" + $clientSecret

$url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + $tenantId + "/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod $url -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body

Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName divyesh@myorg.com -AccessToken $response.access_token
Connect-AzAccount -AccessToken $response.access_token -AccountId 'divyesh@myorg.com'
```

I am getting access token successfully but could not able to connect to **ExchangeOnline** and **AzureAD**. It is giving me errors like the below for **ExchangeOnline**.

```
UnAuthorized
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ExchangeOnlineManagement\3.1.0\netFramework\ExchangeOnlineManagement.psm1:733 char:21
+                     throw $_.Exception;
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnAuthorized
```

and for **AzureAD**

```
WARNING: Unable to acquire a token for tenant 'organizations' with error 'Authentication failed.'
Connect-AzAccount : Authentication failed.
At line:16 char:1
+ Connect-AzAccount -AccessToken $response.access_token -AccountId 'div ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], CloudException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand
```

I am not sure what is wrong here?

Comment: Are you able to connect with the original access token before you generated a new access token from refresh token?

Comment: I did not check it because I was generating an access token in my web-app. Now, I checked it and it is also giving me the same error.

Comment: Note: when you request an access token, you need to specify the scopes that define the resources and operations that an application can access and perform on behalf of a user. In your case, you are using `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`, which is a static scope for all the permissions defined in the app registration. If you've not defined the right permissions in your app registration, you won't get them in your token.

Comment: In my app I have AuditLog.Read.All DeviceManagementConfiguration.Read.All DeviceManagementConfiguration.ReadWrite.All Directory.Read.All Directory.ReadWrite.All IdentityRiskyUser.Read.All Policy.Read.All RoleAssignmentSchedule.Read.Directory RoleAssignmentSchedule.ReadWrite.Directory RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory RoleManagement.Read.Directory RoleManagement.Read.All SecurityEvents.Read.All SecurityEvents.ReadWrite.All User.Read.All User.ReadWrite.All permissions.

Comment: Said permissions would be at least `full_access_as_app` (for Exchange Online) and `User.Read` (at least) for AzureAD. Once you have added these permissions in the Azure portal, you will need to grant admin consent if the permissions require it. This step is necessary for the permissions to take effect. After this, the access token you receive should include the permissions you specified. Do note that changing the permissions in the Azure portal does not change the permissions in existing tokens; you will need to get a new access token after modifying the permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of access token, you need to use `AccessToken` parameter with the `Organization` parameter.

You've configured application permissions for the app in Azure Active Directory and have an access token for a daemon/background service, so you cannot combine `AccessToken` parameter with `UserPrincipalName`

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName xxx -AccessToken yyy
```

#### Steps:

##### Generate access token with the correct scope

When generating access token you are using scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` but the correct one should be `https://outlook.office365.com/.default`

To generate access token use this script

```
$clientId = "7b2cd291-87e9-49fc-888e-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
$clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$tenantId = "baf62cb4-4cc6-4af9-a3c1-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
$body = "client_id=" + $clientId + "&scope=https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office365.com%2F.default&grant_type=client_credentials&client_secret=" + $clientSecret

$url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + $tenantId + "/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod $url -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

##### Connect

Use `Organization` and `AccessToken` parameters for connecting

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Organization '<your_domain_name>.onmicrosoft.com' -AccessToken $response.access_token
```

The steps above suppose that you've [assigned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#assign-azure-ad-roles-to-the-application) the correct Azure role to your application and [modified the manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#assign-azure-ad-roles-to-the-application:%7E:text=select%20Manifest.-,On%20the%20Manifest%20page,-that%20opens%2C%20find).